# How to use serverless framework without destroying API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a problem using the serverless framework. I have two services with the same API Gateway. When I remove one of my services, API Gateway will be removed too. I want to remove one of my services but not remove API Gateway.

Comment: Have you tried asking in https://forum.serverless.com - I would love to hear if that is possible as well. I'm not sure it is. Are you using [shared gateway](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources)?

Comment: Post that as an answer and I will upvote it, Michael, because using the shared gateway indeed solves the problem as long as both services are using the same Gateway

Comment: Don't put the API Gateway in the same template/stack as the services. They can import the API from a different template, then it won't be destroyed when you tear down the service stack.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi you can also use `DeletionPolicy: Retain` to avoid accidental deletion. [read more here](https://seed.run/blog/how-to-prevent-accidentally-deleting-serverless-resources)